# ExactTarget Serverside Javascript: Is there any way to populate a list's attributes into a Data Extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I have a list and when using the following code:

```
var myList = List.Init("TestList");
var subs = myList.Subscribers.Retrieve();
Write(Stringify(subs));
```

I retrieve these attributes:

```
ID  :   184408991
EmailAddress    :   x@x.com
SubscriberKey   :   x@x.com
PartnerKey  :   null
Status  :   Active
CreatedDate :   2014-12-24T02:14:00.000
UnsubscribedDate    :   0001-01-01T00:00:00.000
```

I would like to find the "FirstName" values for this list based subscriber and populate it into a Data Extension to be segmented using a Query Activity later.

Is there any way to find the "FirstName" attribute for list based subscribers using SSJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will first need to initialize an individual **subscriber** object.  You can then use the **Attributes.Retrieve()** function to return the attributes and values for a specific subscriber.

```
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");
var subObj = Subscriber.Init("SubKey");
var attributes = subObj.Attributes.Retrieve();
```

You may want to refer to the following online help page.
http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/subscriber_server_side_javascript_library/